# Convert an XML file to R Data Frame and extract an attribute

Tags: r, xml

I am trying to convert the below XML file to a data frame with data time also as a column of the data frame but I am unable to extract the date time attribute. Any ideas on how to do this in R? A demonstration using a sample code will be helpful to understand how to do this in R.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Group  snapshotTime="2018-05-30T19:33:44.352Z">
<Links>
<rel>self</rel>
<href>https:cloud.com/Group/1</href>
</Links>
<Links>
<rel>last</rel>
<href>https:cloud.com/Group/6</href>
</Links>
<Links>
<rel>next</rel>
<href>https:cloud.com/Group/2</href>
</Links>
<Equipment>
<EquipmentHeader>
<Name>CASE IH</Name>
<Model>1100</Model>
<EquipmentID> Desk</EquipmentID>
<SerialNumber>1231</SerialNumber>
<PIN>123</PIN>
</EquipmentHeader>
<Location datetime="2012-06-25T11:14:54.000Z">
<Latitude>12.573722</Latitude>
<Longitude>-45.515805</Longitude>
</Location>
<Ophrs datetime="2012-03-01T17:42:37.000Z">
<Hour>1968.80</Hour>
</Ophrs>
</Equipment>
<Equipment>
<EquipmentHeader>
<Name>CALL</Name>
<Model>L2048</Model>
<EquipmentID>1MM772GP4</EquipmentID>
<SerialNumber>1TT772GPVJF688214</SerialNumber>
<PIN>1TT772G4</PIN>
</EquipmentHeader>
<Location datetime="2018-05-30T19:22:46.000Z">
<Latitude>15.518556</Latitude>
<Longitude>-55.422444</Longitude>
</Location>
<CumulativeIdleHours datetime="2018-05-30T19:02:46.000Z">
<Hour>14.74</Hour>
</CumulativeIdleHours>
<Ophrs datetime="2018-05-30T19:22:48.000Z">
<Hour>52.35</Hour>
</Ophrs>
<Distance datetime="2018-05-30T19:02:46.000Z">
<OdometerUnits>kilometre</OdometerUnits>
<Odometer>130.9</Odometer>
</Distance>
<FuelUsed datetime="2018-05-30T19:02:46.000Z">
<FuelUnits>litre</FuelUnits>
<FuelConsumed>395</FuelConsumed>
</FuelUsed>
</Equipment>
</Group>
```

Comment: did you notice that in the xml you provide there's a missing opening "<" before one of the "Location datetime"?

Comment: StackOveflow is not a code-writing service. We help earnest efforts when OPs run into issues. Please show us what you attempted and any errors/undesired results.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you would get the `datetime` attribute, for example, for the `Location` nodes:

```html
library("xml2")
library("tidyverse")

temp <- '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Group  snapshotTime="2018-05-30T19:33:44.352Z">
<Links>
<rel>self</rel>
<href>https:cloud.com/Group/1</href>
</Links>
<Links>
<rel>last</rel>
<href>https:cloud.com/Group/6</href>
</Links>
<Links>
<rel>next</rel>
<href>https:cloud.com/Group/2</href>
</Links>
<Equipment>
<EquipmentHeader>
<Name>CASE IH</Name>
<Model>1100</Model>
<EquipmentID> Desk</EquipmentID>
<SerialNumber>1231</SerialNumber>
<PIN>123</PIN>
</EquipmentHeader>
<Location datetime="2012-06-25T11:14:54.000Z">
<Latitude>12.573722</Latitude>
<Longitude>-45.515805</Longitude>
</Location>
<Ophrs datetime="2012-03-01T17:42:37.000Z">
<Hour>1968.80</Hour>
</Ophrs>
</Equipment>
<Equipment>
<EquipmentHeader>
<Name>CALL</Name>
<Model>L2048</Model>
<EquipmentID>1MM772GP4</EquipmentID>
<SerialNumber>1TT772GPVJF688214</SerialNumber>
<PIN>1TT772G4</PIN>
</EquipmentHeader>
<Location datetime="2018-05-30T19:22:46.000Z">
<Latitude>15.518556</Latitude>
<Longitude>-55.422444</Longitude>
</Location>
<CumulativeIdleHours datetime="2018-05-30T19:02:46.000Z">
<Hour>14.74</Hour>
</CumulativeIdleHours>
<Ophrs datetime="2018-05-30T19:22:48.000Z">
<Hour>52.35</Hour>
</Ophrs>
<Distance datetime="2018-05-30T19:02:46.000Z">
<OdometerUnits>kilometre</OdometerUnits>
<Odometer>130.9</Odometer>
</Distance>
<FuelUsed datetime="2018-05-30T19:02:46.000Z">
<FuelUnits>litre</FuelUnits>
<FuelConsumed>395</FuelConsumed>
</FuelUsed>
</Equipment>
</Group>'

temp %>% xml2::read_xml() %>% rvest::xml_nodes("Location") %>% xml2::xml_attr("datetime")
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: ,Can you please show a code of converting the entire XML file into a data frame? I am having difficulty in retrieving the units Kilometer and litre. Please let me know a sample code. Thanks!